# .map usage in an object

Tags: javascript, object, array.prototype.map

just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of .map functionality. This is unfortunately something I'm struggling to get my head around.

If I had an object, lets say the following:

```
const myPetsAndFood = {
    pets:[
    { 
        species: "dog",
        breed: "Labrador",
        age: 12
    },
    {
        species: "cat",
        breed: "unknown",
        age: 7,
    },
    {
        species: "fish",
        breed: "goldfish",
        age: 1,
    }
],
    food: [
        {
            dogfood: 15.00,
        },
        {
            catfood: 11.00,
        },
        {
            fishfood: 4.00,
        }
    ],
};
```

Could anyone explain how I'd utilise .map to obtain the data values of age and price if possible please?
A brief explanation or example is more than suffice, I'd appreciate any time/input possible. In all probability, I'll be sat here reading and trying to figure it out in the mean time.

If you got this far - Thank you for your time.

Comment: It would be better if `food` were an object like `{dogfood: 15.00, catfood: 11.00, fishfood: 4.00}`. Why use an array of objects with different keys?

Comment: here is it guaranteed that the order is same for pets and foods. if not Barmar's approach makes things much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the .map can only be used with arrays. This way you can not do something similar to:

```
myPetsAndFood.map()
```

Let's say you want do console.log the age. You would have to get the array first. So:

```
myPetsAndFood.pets.map((pet) => {
   console.log(pet.age)
})
```

And it would print 12, followed by 7 followed by 1. If you want to store it inside an array you can create an array and use .push("//infos wanted to be pushed//")

Comment: Brilliant - Thank you! 
I meant to reply earlier, sorry for the late reply. I got wrapped up in the assignment.
Makes a lot more sense now that I know I need to target the array specifically instead of the object, makes further sense now that I know I can name and call a variable inside of `.map(item, species)` as well!

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.keys(myPetsAndFood).map(function(key, index) {
  console.log(myPetsAndFood[key][0].dogfood);
  console.log(myPetsAndFood[key][0].age);
});
```

You are going to have to figure out a way to replace the 0 with some sort of counter that will increment.

Answer (score 0):

`map` is a method of arrays, it doesn't exist on objects. You could use it on the arrays within the object ( `myPetsAndFood.pets.map( /* ... */ )` ) but you'd have to use a `for` loop or some other technique to parse each item in the object.

An example of how to use the `map` function for one of your arrays:

```
const agesArray = myPetsAndFood.pets.map((item) => {
    return item.age;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have imbricated arrays here. This makes it so you have to go into your wanted array first before being able to execute your map.

For example: `myPetsAndFood.pets.map(function)`

The way that `.map` works is it executes your function on every element in your array and returns an array with the equivalency([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).

Therefore, in order to get the `age` of every `pet`, you have to tell your function to get your `age` property of your objects.

For example: `myPetsAndFood.pets.map((pet) => pet.age)`

This will return an array containing only the age of every one of your pets.

Now the problem with this is your second array. We cannot call the `.map` function on that array because your different properties don't have the same name. Therefore, your `.map` won't have any common ground to return a sensible array.

We can fix this issue by splitting your one variable into two: `name` and `price` for example. After this change, we can now call the `.map` on your array properly by telling it which property you need.

For example: `myPetsAndFood.foods.map((food) => food.price)`

Below is a full code snippet which should show off the above description.

```js
const myPetsAndFood = {
  pets:[
    { 
      species: "dog",
      breed: "Labrador",
      age: 12
    },
    {
      species: "cat",
      breed: "unknown",
      age: 7,
    },
    {
      species: "fish",
      breed: "goldfish",
      age: 1,
    }
  ],
  foods: [
    {
      name: "dog",
      price: 15.00,
    },
    {
      name: "cat",
      price: 11.00,
    },
    {
      name: "fish",
      price: 4.00,
    }
  ],
};

const catAge = myPetsAndFood.pets.map((pet) => pet.age)
const foodPrice = myPetsAndFood.foods.map((food) => food.price)


console.log(catAge)
console.log(foodPrice)
```